# Need to recover android system for soft bricked Onda v919 4G

Tags: recovery-mode, tablet, twrp, 4g

I have an Onda v919 4G that I messed with and broke. I changed a line in the /system/etc/parameters file. I wanted the system to use my SD card (256 Gb) as the primary storage device for my apps and data.  That change caused my droid to refuse to boot up. If I could mount the file system and just edit that file things would be just fine. But no.......

I can't just mount the file system and edit the file. Now I have to burn the blood of a virgin or something so that I can fix this thing.

I tried using fastboot but apparently my tablet doesn't support flashing from fastboot which begs the question 'what the hell is fastboot for?' I've got no clue.

Can I mount the file system at all? I'm using an ubuntu 14 laptop as my primary work machine. Unfortunately I've looked everywhere on the net I can think. But I haven't found anything useful/understandable. Anyone able to teach a fool how to recover from his mess up? My tablet runs on an MTK8572 chip if that helps matters. An 'lsusb' command in terminal identifies my tablet as HTC (High Tech Computer Corp.) Dream / ADP1 / G1 / Magic / Tattoo. Again, I hope this is helpful.

Peace to you and yours.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the system/etc/parameters directory. What you have done is altered the system configurations that appear to be used at boot. You would have needed to install a custom recovery when you rooted your device. Fastboot is ,in essence ,the equivalent of that recovery except it is included in the Android SDK(Software Development Kit).Most custom recoveries also include a fastboot option.  You will have to scour the web to find a version of the stock firmware for your tablet.

For future reference, be very careful when accessing or dealing with the system directory and especially the /etc directory as it contains configuration files for your Android system.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying the system directory you have root.
If you have root, the device came pre-rooted or you used a one click method or you have a custom recovery installed.
If you have a custom recovery installed the approach is to boot to recovery and connect the device to pc.

- Open a terminal and run `adb shell mount /system`.
- Then run `adb pull /system/the/file/you/porked`.
- Correct/revert the changes you made.
- Then run `adb push the-file-you-unporked /system/wherever/it-goes`.
- Lastly, run `adb shell chmod 644 /system/wherever/the-filed-you-unporked-is/name-of-file`.

You may need to establish some udev rules for your device however.
See this http://hackaday.com/2009/09/18/how-to-write-udev-rules/

You will also need to install android-tools-adb if you have not done so already. If they are not in your current known repository for Ubuntu, you will need to add the correct repos to etc/apt/sources.list or goto github or ubuntu source download page and get the source and compile it for your OS. You can also acquire the source by running `apt-get source android-tools` followed by `apt-get build-dep android-tools` to satisfy any build dependency issues. May the schwartz be with you.

Answer (score 0):

When you changed the SD-card to your primary directory that made Android wanna boot from the SD-card because he thinks all of his files are there now. But ofc there are none of his files cuz they are all in /system on the internal storage. The only way to access the files is over adb (which probably isn't turned on if you always turn it off after finishing using it like everyone else who is concerned about his phone security) or a custom recovery.

Btw NEVER, NEVER tamper with major system files without having a backup/ knowing 200% what the effects are.